# Add Next and Previous on Pop up image by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pop up image and it works well already. On this pop up image I need next and previous to change the image but I don't know how to set next and previous on the pop up image.
Here is `HTML`:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul class="image-list">
            <li><img src="photos/g1.jpg" alt="Photo number 1" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)"/></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g2.jpg" alt="Photo number 2" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)"/></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g3.jpg" alt="Photo number 3" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)"/></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g4.jpg" alt="Photo number 4" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g5.jpg" alt="Photo number 5" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g6.jpg" alt="Photo number 6" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g7.jpg" alt="Photo number 7" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g8.jpg" alt="Photo number 8" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g9.jpg" alt="Photo number 9" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
            <li><img src="photos/g10.jpg" alt="Photo number 10" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this.src)" /></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navigation" id="nav">
            <span class="previous" id="prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="next" id="next">Next</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
ul.image-list{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
 ul.image-list li{
    display: inline-block;
}
 ul.image-list li img{
    width: 190px;
    min-width: 70px;
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
 }
 ul.image-list li img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

`Javascript`:

```
    function view(src)
        {
            var viewer = document.getElementById("viewer");
            viewer.innerHTML ='<img src="' + src + '" id="img"/>';
            viewer.innerHTML =
            var img = document.getElementById("img");
            var iw=0, ih=0;
            var dw=0, dh=0;

            img.onload=function(){
                document.getElementById("ov").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("nav").style.display="block";
                viewer.style.display="block";
                iw = viewer.offsetWidth;
                ih = viewer.offsetHeight;
                dw = window.innerWidth;
                dh = window.innerHeight;
                viewer.style.top = parseInt(dh/2-ih/2) + "px";
                viewer.style.left = parseInt(dw/2-iw/2) + "px";
            };
        }
        function hide2()
        {
            document.getElementById("viewer").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("ov").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("nav").style.display="none";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz try This one

[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Simple-jQuery-Popup-Gallery-Lightbox-Plugin-Popup.html)

```
 $(".popup").popup({
    transparentLayer : true,
    gallery : true,
    galleryTitle : "<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/">Gallery</a>1 Title",
    imgaeDesc : true,
    galleryCounter : true,
    08
    imageDesc : true,
    09
    autoSize : false,

    boxHeight : 600,

    boxWidth : 500,

    shadowLength : 0,

    transition : 0,
        onOpen : function() {

    console.log("opened the box .popup");

    },

    onClose : function() {

    console.log("closed the box .popup");

    }



    });
```

plz try anotherone example:

[Demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/popup-images.html)

Answer (score 0):

fox example

```
  <li><img src="photos/g1.jpg" alt="Photo number 1" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" onclick="view(this)"/></li>
```

add  window.lastImageShown for knowing last selected image

```
 function view(image)
        {
            window.lastImageShown = image;
            var viewer = document.getElementById("viewer");
            viewer.innerHTML ='<img src="' + image.src + '" id="img"/>';
            /** your code */

 function hide2()
        {
            window.lastImageShown = null;
            document.getElementById("viewer").style.display="none";
           /** your code */
```

and use  window.lastImageShown for switching between images

```
    //window.lastImageShown - image
    //window.lastImageShown.parentNode - li

    //window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling - next li
    //window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild - next image
    function next(){
       if(window.lastImageShown && window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling){
          view(window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild);
       }
    }
 //window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling - prev li
 //window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild - prev image
    function prev(){
       if(window.lastImageShown && window.lastImageShown.parentNode.nextSibling){
          view(window.lastImageShown.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild);
       }
    }

 <div class="navigation" id="nav">
            <span class="previous" id="prev"  onclick="prev()">Prev</span>
            <span class="next" id="next"  onclick="next()">Next</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Excues me sir, could you say detail about your code? I don't understand.

Comment: what exactly you don't understand?What part?

Comment: Thank. I understand you code but my main purpose is show the next and prev over the popup image. Could you help me?